# Limiting the amount of entities a Mobspawner can spawn

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

[Java Spigot / Minecraft] Is there a way to create a plugin that limits the amount of mobs a spawner can spawn on a server?
For example I want to create a mob spawner that automatically stops spawning mobs or destroys itself after spawning 500 mobs.

I already thought about if it is possible, but I didn't know how to track at the mob spawn event, which spawner spawned a mob and how to assign a certain value to this spawner, which determines how many mobs it can spawn.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe you should [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CreatureSpawnEvent` event, check where the entity was spawned and increment a counter or a dictionary of the spawners on the server and delete the entity if the limit is surpassed. The Spigot docs are [here](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/event/entity/CreatureSpawnEvent.html).